# iOS secure directory for specific app

Tags: ios, security

Is there any way to make directory in iOS secured and protected just for my app?
in my application user buys books and I save books on documents sub directory, so I don't want any other application to access this directory 
any suggestions ?
should I encrypt this data ?

Answer (score 1):

The documents folder is indeed sandboxed from other apps, but it is not safe from 3rd party utilities which lets you check the iPhone's file system (jailbreak not required) , such as iExplorer.
If you want to secure your app data you should read about the data protection api's in Apple's developer portal. There's a nice WWDC lecture as well (I think its from 2011).
Another solution could be packing your material in a secure format , such as an encrypted zip file (some sort of password derived from the device's uuid you create on the spot).

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested to take a look at Data protection for iOS:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4175

[What are the new "iOS data protection APIs"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081102/what-are-the-new-ios-data-protection-apis)

[Data Protection on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958362/data-protection-on-ios)

[Implementing and Testing iOS data protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155789/implementing-and-testing-ios-data-protection)

Answer (score 0):

The documents folder for your application is sandboxed and can be utilized only by your application.  If you are storing resources to be used by your app, this is the place to put them.

Comment: Lou is right. The data could be access through something like iExplorer.

Comment: The OP's question is about securing his data from other applications which may be installed on the device (which does not seem to be sensitive other than it is purchased content).  Most applications store purchased and downloaded content in the applications documents directory.